# Why does img.thumbnail adjustment raise FileNotFoundError [Errno2] No such file directory?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, python-imaging-library

I have a django blog application that is deployed on Heroku and has images being served from AWS S3 Bucket.  When a user attempts to upload an image, we use PIL to thumbnail resize the dimensions based on an if condition (as shown in *models.py* below).

When I attempt to update profile image, it throws the dreaded:

```
FileNotFoundError at /profile/

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'profile_pics/0umkn7tybif11.jpg'
```

The traceback of the error also shows what appear to be these key lines:

```
 /app/users/signals.py in save_profile

        instance.profile.save()

     ...

▶ Local vars
/app/users/models.py in save

                img.save(self.image.name)

     ...

▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in save

                    fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")

     ...

▶ Local vars
```

My **models.py** file seems to contain the code being addressed in this error:

```
from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User 
    from PIL import Image 
    from django.core.files.storage import default_storage as storage

    class Profile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

        def save(self, **kwargs):
            super().save()

            img = Image.open(storage.open(self.image.name))

            if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
                output_size = (300, 300)
                img.thumbnail(output_size)
                img.save(self.image.name)
```

Lastly, if I remove the following code from the models.py file, the app functions properly:

```
if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
    output_size = (300, 300)
    img.thumbnail(output_size)
    img.save(self.image.name)
```

It seems as though the img.save(self.image.name) is not properly accessing the s3 bucket pathway?  What is the reason for this and how would I properly implement this thumbnail size adjustment.